# ExtJS 5 - Observable.dom is null IE 8 and IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, extjs5

I have a window in which there is a form. This window will be shown on clicking a Upload button.

Since i had to support multiple file uploads and also show them in a grid. I am adding a new filebutton every time a new file is added and a reference of it is added into the grid.

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    itemId: 'form-itemid',
    width: 100,
    height:'100%',
    fieldId: 1,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        name: 'files',
        itemId: 'file-upload-'+me.fieldId+'-id',
        buttonOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Add Files',
        listeners: {
            change: function(view, value, eOpts) {
                var form = this.up('form');
                form.onfileChange(view, value, eOpts);
            }
        }
        }],
        onfileChange: function(view, value, eOpts) {
            if (value != "") {
                var form = this;
                me.fieldId = App.util.AppConfig.getWinCount();

                var newUploadControl = {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    buttonOnly: true,
                    anchor: '100%',
                    buttonText: 'Add Files',
                    name: 'files',
                    itemId: 'file-upload-' + me.fieldId+'-id',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(view, value, eOpts) {
                            form.onfileChange(view, value, eOpts);
                        }
                    }
              };
              view.hide();
              form.insert(0, newUploadControl);

              fileStore.getStore().add({
                  'filename': filename,
                  'fileId': me.fieldId - 1
              });

}
```

After the upload is completed i am closing the window.

```
 window.close();
```

At this point, in IE9 and IE8 i am getting the error 
"Unable to get value of property 'id': object is null or undefined" in Dom.js unsubscribe() method for an Observable having target **fileinput**.

The error occurred on the following line in the file

```
 dom = observable.dom; // results in null
 id = dom.id; (Error here) // hence dom.id gives an error here
```

From inspecting in the browser i can see that the fileinput has its 'id'.

Not sure why the dom object is null.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed on 5.1, I would consider updating the whole application as a BUG FIX for 5.0.x is not likely to come around anytime soon.

Comment: Is there any risk when i upgrade the application to 5.0.1?